# FULLSCREEN SLIT SLIDER AUTOPLAY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-slider

I am using this slider. Everything working well but having problem in autoplay. When I click on navigation arrow on slider or on Nav dot on bottom. After that autoplay not working.

This is the link [CLICK HERE](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/)

Auto play function not there, you have to download it and make autoplay : true in Js.

Js Name : jquery.slitslider.js

```
$.Slitslider.defaults = {
    // transitions speed
    speed : 800,
    // if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
    optOpacity : false,
    // amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
    translateFactor : 230,
    // maximum possible angle
    maxAngle : 25,
    // maximum possible scale
    maxScale : 2,
    // slideshow on / off
    autoplay : true,
    // keyboard navigation
    keyboard : true,
    // time between transitions
    interval : 6000,
    // callbacks
    onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) {
        return false;
    },
    onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the script contains code like that whenever you pressed the function stop the slideshow

```
switch (keyCode) {

                case arrow.left :

                    self._stopSlideshow(); //this line stops autoplay
                    self._navigate( 'prev' );
                    break;

                case arrow.right :

                    self._stopSlideshow();
                    self._navigate( 'next' );
                    break;

            }
```

Comment: Then, what should i do to keep it changing even after click on these arrows or nav dots ?

Comment: I did, but it's still same case, autoplay not working

Comment: Thanks man :) it's done. i search morel links like that (_stopSlideshow();) and commented them . it's working now :) 
thanks alot

Comment: Hi, i having again a problem, when i click on main links and again coming back on the slider page..  the slider not working . this is the test site .http://coeindia.in/test/kubic/

Comment: i tested it after clicking navigation returned to main page it plays a slide

Comment: Hi Sridhar, I tried it alot. if you click on navigation links ( like, about us , contact so so) then get bag to home page. then the slider not working and repeating same slide as we come to home page. it's not happening always but it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do much just make the autoplay option true where 
autoplay : false,

///

```
    $.Slitslider.defaults = {
    // transitions speed
    speed : 800,
    // if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
    optOpacity : false,
    // amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
    translateFactor : 230,
    // maximum possible angle
    maxAngle : 25,
    // maximum possible scale
    maxScale : 2,
    // slideshow on / off
    autoplay : true,
    // keyboard navigation
    keyboard : true,
    // time between transitions
    interval : 4000,
    // callbacks
    onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; },
    onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; }
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in parameters and start the slideshow again after user interaction.

```
$('#slider').slitslider({
    autoplay: true, 
    interval: 6000,
    onAfterChange: function(slide, idx) {
        slitslider._startSlideshow(); // Starts the autoplay again
        return false;
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

find this code in jquery.slitslider.js and change 2 false options to true, then add `_startSlideshow()` function to bottom of it

```
_stopSlideshow: function() {
        if ( this.options.autoplay ) {

            clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
            this.isPlaying = true; // set this to true
            this.options.autoplay = true; // set this to true
            this._startSlideshow(); // Add this line

        }

    }
```